# Whats meaning of this regex?

Tags: regex

In the folllowing regex:

`[a-zA-Z_]?\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"`

What does `\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"` mean?

Comment: That really depends on the language this regex is used in.

Comment: What flavor of regex is it? Have you looked at the relevant reference and made at least some effort to figure this out? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Try looking at http://marvin.cs.uidaho.edu/~heckendo/CS445F07/regex.html and http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the description:

```
[              # start character class
  a-zA-Z         # case insensitive character match
  _              # underscores are allowed too
]              # end character class
?              # match zero or one time
(              # start group
  \\.            # dot character
  |              # OR
  [              # start character class
    ^              # match any character
    \\"            # except double quote
  ]              # end character class
)              # end group
*              # match zero or more occurrences
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like java, so breaking down

```
\"(\\.|[^\\"])*\"
```

we get:

- `\"` a literal quote `"`
- `(` start group
- `\\.` literal dot
- `|` logical "or"
- `[` start character class
- `^` negation
- `\\"` unnecessarily escaped quote - equivalent to `\"` - also should either have 3 or 1 backslashes, so this is a syntax error as it stands
- `]` end character class
- `)` end group
- `*` any number of
- `\"` a literal quote `"`

All together, this means: Any number of dots (including zero dots) between quotes

The character class is an attempt to not be greedy, but there's an easier way to do this - just use the "non-greedy" operator `*?`. Ie it could be replaced by:

```
\"\\.*?\"
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  I'm not familiar enough with Java (if this is indeed from Java) to comment on the detailed syntax, but this certainly looks like the common idiom for allowing backslash escapes inside quotes.  In other words, any number of characters between double quotes, allowing for backslash-escaped double quotes (or backslashed anything, in fact).